# Performance issue in windows 10 compared with Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a program developed in VB.Net. A specific operation in the application uses memory(arrays) to store the details. We use threading in the application.

The application was running perfectly around 15 mins in Windows 7 OS.
The problem started when we have migrated into new OS i.e. Windows 10.

It takes around 11 hours to complete the same operation which looks abnormal in any kind of application.

Can any one help me out this to sort this down?

Sys Config:

> Windows 10: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500T CPU @ 2.70GHz 2.71GHz, 8GB RAM,
>   4 Core
>  Windows 7:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 550 @ 3.20GHz 3.20GHz,
>   4GB RAM, 4 Core.

The code which taking more time to get execute is added here:

```
Private Sub ComputeAverageMark(ByVal ExamAndMarkDS As DataSet, ByRef ErrorDetailsObj As ErrorDetails)
    Try
        Dim ExamValue As New Exam
        Dim ExamForAnalysisValue As New ExamForAnalysis
        Dim ExamDT As New DataTable
        Dim ExamListArgsValue As ExamListArgs
        Dim MarkDT As New DataTable
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim ExamListArgsList As New List(Of ExamListArgs)

        ExamDT = ExamAndMarkDS.Tables(0)
        MarkDT = ExamAndMarkDS.Tables(2)

        Dim MarkHashTable As Hashtable = GetMarkHashTable(MarkDT)

        For Each ExamDR As DataRow In ExamDT.Rows

            count = count + 1
            If MarkHashTable.ContainsKey(ExamDR.Item("ExamName")) Then
                MarkDT = MarkHashTable(ExamDR.Item("ExamName"))
            Else
                MarkDT = MarkDT.Clone
            End If

            ExamListArgsValue = New ExamListArgs(ExamDR, False, MarkDT, True, 1, ErrorDetailsObj)

            ExamListArgsList.Add(ExamListArgsValue)

            If count >= 100 Then
                Dim paralleOptions As New ParallelOptions
                paralleOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4

                Parallel.ForEach(ExamListArgsList.ToArray, paralleOptions, Sub(ExamListArgs)
                                                                                ComputeAverageMark(ExamListArgs)
                                                                            End Sub)
                ExamListArgsList.Clear()
                count = 0
            End If

        Next

        If count > 0 AndAlso count < 100 Then
            Dim paralleOptions As New ParallelOptions
            paralleOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            Parallel.ForEach(ExamListArgsList.ToArray, paralleOptions, Sub(ExamListArgs)
                                                                                ComputeAverageMark(ExamListArgs)
                                                                            End Sub)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `ExamListArgs` look like and show us `ComputeAverageMark(ExamListArgs)` does.

Comment: add some debugging/tracing to a log with dates and times to be certain which section of code is causing the issue...right now you just have one long method..break it down into further parts